# advise for HQL as need toreplace the criteria

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have use criteria as shown below , could you please advise how we can replace this with HQL

```
public List<abc> getdef(String numericid) {
        Criteria query = session.createCriteria(abc.class);

        if(numericid!=null) {
            query.add(Restrictions.eq("digitalid", numericid));
        }
      List<abc> cghflist = query.list();


        return cghflist;
    }
```

Comment: I hope you have a good reason to translate the criteria, this one may look fine, but dinamic queries with HQL are a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query;
if(numericid != null){
   query = session.createQuery("from abc where digitalid = :id");
   query.setParameter("id", numericid);
}else{
   session.createQuery("from abc");
}
List list = query.list();
```

If the query is more coplex and there are more than one parameter that need to be added only if they are `!= null` you should construct your string query for every parameter.

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("from abc where 1=1");

    if(someParam != null){
      sql.append(" and someParam = :someParam");
    }
```

and you need to take care when you set the parameters.